# Get Access to parent methods and variables through DOM - Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular5

Hello is there a way to have access to the upper level component and it's variables and methods through the DOM ?

In my Example the Angular Code is generated dynamically and there could be different Components. But the Child does know which methods and variable the parent DOM Component has.

Is there a way to get Access to the methods and variables?

For Example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhpnf8

```
<hello name="grandparent1">
    <some-other-component name="parent1">
        <div>
            <hello name="grandchild1">
            </hello>
            <hello name="grandchild2">
            </hello>
        </div>
    </some-other-component>
</hello>
```

Comment: may you give some example what you want to do? in your example?

Comment: I made a demo app. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhpnf8

Comment: not good way is using ViewContainerRef, check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enfnsm .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need simply

```
import { ParentPage } from '../../pages/well-control/parent';
.
.
.
parent: ParentPage;
parent1: any;
.
.
.
constructor(...){
parent.method1();//you can use it anywhere
parent1 = parent.variable1;
}
```

Comment: there is no need to create instance of parent in child class, you can access parent methods by calling them : ```this.method1()```

Comment: maybe you mean super not this, however, by above mentioned answer you can use any component easily.